# ngx-translate not working in tooltip and kendo grid title

Tags: angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

ngx-translate not working in tool-tip-content attribute in angular 8 as well for kendo grid title also. It throwing an error that

Can't bind to 'tool-tip-content' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("    <a class="text-dark tool-tip-definition tool-tip-position--left m-0 lh-0"
[ERROR ->]tool-tip-content="{{'Users' | translate}}"

`<a class="text-dark tool-tip-definition tool-tip-position--left m-0 lh-0"  tool-tip-content="{{'Users' | translate: Language}}" aria-label="Email Contact"  href="mailto:{{item.partnername | splitEngPartner: '(':'email'}}"> <i class="material-icons editIcon" type="button" aria-hidden="true">forward_to_inbox</i> </a>`

fr.json
`{ "Users": "Utilisatrices" }`

In kendo grid
`<kendo-grid-column field="productName" title="{{'ProductName' | translate}}" [width]="60"> </kendo-grid-column>`

I tried many ways but nothing had worked for me. Please suggest me how to do this.